# running a NodeJS process with forever-monitor on development server

Tags: node.js, amazon-lightsail, forever-monitor

I am attempting to run my expressJS app continuously
on a server using forever-monitor.
I don't get any errors however my app does not keep running as expected,
the process exits after 3 restarts.
Can I omit the max value here or what am I missing to run the app continuously?

Info: I am deploying it to a AWS lightsail server.

the code I have implemented comes from the forever-monitor git repo.

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
max: 3,
silent: true,
args: []
});

child.on('exit', function () {
console.log('program has exited after 3 restarts');
});

child.start();
```

Comment: The documentation on GitHub says that 'max' is an option. So you should be able to just omit it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, would it be better to set it to another value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install both forever and forever-monitor dependencies to get the app running continuously. 
The application runs as expected now after closing the CLI session.

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
max:3,
silent: true,
sourceDir: '/app.js',
watch:true,
args: []
});

child.on('watch:restart', function(info) {
console.error('Restaring script because ' + info.file + ' changed');
});

child.on('restart', function() {
console.error('Forever restarting script for ' + child.times + ' time');
});

child.on('exit:code', function(code) {
console.error('Forever detected script exited with code ' + code);
});

child.start();
```